# Texments/minted not working - Undefined control sequence

Tags: errors, minted

I'm trying to add some syntax highlighting to my code and found two packages: texments and minted.
I tried to use them, but I'm getting errors while trying to build. I used following code to test both packages:

```
\pygment{python}{ print "Hello World!"}
```

All what I get is errors:

---

```
**! Undefined control sequence.**

<argument> \PY
{k}{print} \PY {l+s}{"}\PY {l+s}{Hello World!}\PY {l+s}{"}
l.2 ...PY{l+s}{"}\PY{l+s}{Hello World!}\PY{l+s}{"}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

**! Undefined control sequence.**

<argument> \PY {k}{print} \PY
{l+s}{"}\PY {l+s}{Hello World!}\PY {l+s}{"}
l.2 ...PY{l+s}{"}\PY{l+s}{Hello World!}\PY{l+s}{"}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

**! Undefined control sequence.**

<argument> \PY {k}{print} \PY {l+s}{"}\PY
{l+s}{Hello World!}\PY {l+s}{"}
l.2 ...PY{l+s}{"}\PY{l+s}{Hello World!}\PY{l+s}{"}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

**! Undefined control sequence.**

<argument> ... {l+s}{"}\PY {l+s}{Hello World!}\PY
{l+s}{"}
l.2 ...PY{l+s}{"}\PY{l+s}{Hello World!}\PY{l+s}{"}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
) [6]) [7] (./mk_mall.aux) )
```

---

I have pygments installed, version 1.4.

How can I get everything to work?

Comment: Hi, welcome to tex.sx. Please format error messages as code blocks. They are easier to read this way.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to share another solution for the same issue which couldn't be solved by Frédéric's answer.

In the process of installing minted (and trying to get it to work), I used one TeX file and different settings for python, pdftex and so on. Even compiling Frédéric's example would lead to undefined control sequences.
Cleaning up the subdirectory `_minted-FILENAME` solved this.

Comment: I actually have the same error, though I cannot find the suddirectory `_minted*`, any hint?

Comment: @Auzias It should be in the same directory as your `.tex` file. If it isn't there, Pygments isn't working yet. Assuming you use Windows, have you tried all steps mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108661/how-to-use-minted-under-miktex-and-windows-7)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the record it was a too old version. I upgraded it to v2.2 with the command: `curl -o /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty 
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gpoore/minted/0a8640dddff47ae31a7a0d6e3cf030c82c111907/source/minted.sty`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy error to correct. You are not using the correct syntax. Pygments is the program that `minted` calls. The command (or environment) is `\minted` for a piece of code :

```
\begin{minted}{python}
def f(x) :
    y = x**2
    return y

for x in range(0,10) :
    print f(x)*" " + "Hello World"
\end{minted}
```

For a one-line piece of code, the command is `\mint`. For example,
 `\mint{python}|print "Hello World"|`
Note the delimiter | : the `\mint` command works like the `\verb` command, any symbol (not appearing in your line of code) may be used.

Many more options are available. For example, there is a `listing` environment that puts everything in a floating box. You may also show the line numbers, change the colors, etc ...