# How to use minted under MikTeX and Windows 7?

Tags: miktex, minted

According to `minted` documentation:

> Windows support is sketchy / untested at the moment. There are two
>   complications: installation and usage.......

This question seeks a step by step elaboration of

**How to setup `minted` for use with MikTeX under Windows?**

Comment: I could not find a similar question. If there is any, kindly let me know. This is an attempt to build a reference point.

Comment: Install a virtual machine and work under Unix ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Why to adopt easy methods when there are difficult ones `;-)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`minted` uses Python [`pygments`](http://pygments.org/) library, so you need to:

- Install [`Python`](http://www.python.org/download/), choose any version you like: `x64` or `x86`, it better to choose `2.7.5` version.
- Add `Python` to `PATH`:

  - Hold <kbd>Win</kbd> and press <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
  - Click `Advanced System Settings`.
  - Click `Environment Variables`.
  - Append `;C:\Python27` to the `PATH` variable.
- [Install `python-pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).
- Add `;C:\Python27\Scripts` to the `PATH` variable.
- `pip install pygments` to install `Pygments` (in case you have `Perl` installed, the full path to `pip` should be specified, because `Perl` also has a binary with the same name).
- Сompile with `-shell-escape` option enabled:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{minted}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{minted}[mathescape,
                     linenos,
                     numbersep=5pt,
                     gobble=2,
                     frame=lines,
                     framesep=2mm]{csharp}
        string title = "This is a Unicode π in the sky"
        /*
        Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
        of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
        circle of diameter $d$.
        */
        const double pi = 3.1415926535
      \end{minted}
  \end{document}
  ```

The result should look like:

[image: result]

Comment: I like very much your example. I was trying and finally I think that installed pygments. I usually use winedt and 3 buttons. How could I use -shell-escape option enabled   ?

Comment: @MikaIke Actually, I don't use Winedt so can't answer this. Better to ask this question or to Google it, I think it already have been answered somewhere.

Comment: @MikaIke: Go to `Options` → `Execution Modes` and the in the window that opens, choose `pdflatex` (or any engine that you use). Add `--shell-escape` in `Switches`. See this picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bY3rH.png

Answer (score 7):

Install [python](http://www.python.org/download/) for windows. Then install [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads). This should add `easy_install.exe` file in the `Scripts` folder of your `python` directory (something like:  `C:\Python26\Scripts\` in my computer. It may be different for you.) Add `C:\Python26\Scripts` to your system path using user variables. You may wish to use a user friendly editor: [path editor](http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor/) for this purpose.

Now with internet on, go to the command prompt and type `easy_install pygments`.

[image]

Now you may have to restart your computer. And there you go. Try this test file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted} % loads fancyvrb

\newenvironment{eqnexample}
 {\VerbatimOut{\jobname.tmp}}
 {\endVerbatimOut
  \inputminted{latex}{\jobname.tmp}
  \input{\jobname.tmp}}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnexample}
\begin{align}
  d &= \sqrt{ (x'-x)^2 }
  \\
  e &= 0
\end{align}
\end{eqnexample}

\begin{eqnexample}
\begin{multline}
  d = \sqrt{ (x'-x)^2 }  \\
  = f(x,x')
\end{multline}
\end{eqnexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `pygmentize.cmd` is not really needed, in latest version there is a `pygmentize.exe` inside the `Scripts` folder, so, only adding that folder in `PATH` is necessary.

Comment: @m0nhawk Good to know. I have edited it in my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Also note that in the latest version, having a `pygmentize.cmd` is not just inconsequential, instead its detrimental, preventing you from using `minted`. I just wasted an hour to figure that out.