# Listing with mixed english and russian symbols in comments

Tags: fonts, xetex, listings, languages, cyrillic

I'm using the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package for formatting `.cpp` code in LaTeX. My code needs to have mixed English and Russian words in comments. The font must be monospaced (preffered `Courier` family).

```
/* Prints Hello World */
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main (void){
       printf ("Hello World!"); // This is an english commentary
       return 0; // А это русский комментарий
    }
```

I`m using the following code as an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf[Script=Cyrillic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt[Script=Cyrillic]{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{CppCodeStyle}{
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
language={[ANSI]C++},
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
showstringspaces=false,
morekeywords={include, printf},
commentstyle={},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style={CppCodeStyle}]
/* Prints Hello World */
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
    printf ("Hello World!"); // This is an english commentary
    return 0; // А это русский комментарий
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

As I result XeLaTeX (in MiKTeX 2.9) produces following PDF:

```
/* Prints Hello World */
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main (void){
       printf ("Hello World!"); // This is an english commentary
       return 0; // Аэторусскийкомментарий
    }
```

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images `:(`
As you can see, **all spaces in Russian are ignored**.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136176/1871, I find the unicode limitation of the great `listings` package very annoying; and I don't see a fundamental reason for this limitation. Lenguages like C++ are know accepting unicode variable names, however `listings` is not catching up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe `minted` is an alternative. Please note that you must run `xelatex` with `--shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf[Script=Cyrillic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt[Script=Cyrillic]{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
Test
\begin{minted}{c++}
/* Prints Hello World */
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
    printf ("Hello World!"); // This is an english commentary
    return 0; // А это русский комментарий
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Marco, i forgot to mention that I`m working in Windows environment, I`ve followed the set-up instruction from the `minted` package documentation, but after all instalation procedures I`ve got an error message: "! LaTeX Error: File `document.out.pyg' not found.".

Comment: @Aganezor: I like my comment there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108661/how-to-use-minted-under-miktex-and-windows-7#comment237962_108661 ;-) -- However this is a good point to ask a follow up question if you want to use `minted`

Comment: I figured-out what the problem was - I just need to restart my TeX editor (Eclipse) :) Now everything works fine. Thank you for your help and for very interesting package :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `listings` doesn't work well with Unicode.

A working hack is to enclose the cyrillic comments between a rarely used character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf[Script=Cyrillic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt[Script=Cyrillic]{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{CppCodeStyle}{
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
language={[ANSI]C++},
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
showstringspaces=false,
morekeywords={include, printf},
commentstyle={},
escapeinside=§§,
escapebegin=\begin{russian}\commentfont,
escapeend=\end{russian},
}
\newcommand{\commentfont}{\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style={CppCodeStyle}]
/* Prints Hello World */
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
    printf ("Hello World!"); // This is an english commentary
    return 0; // §А это русский комментарий§
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @egreg, Your solution works, but for big amount of code it`s quite uncomfortable. Besides, for `\lstinputlisting` it will not work :(

Comment: @Aganezor I know. It's a big nuisance. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try to activate LaTeX comment lines with `texcl=true`

This needs no adaption in your source code. You may get problems if your comments contain TeX-commands (e.g. a % in the comments should be masked as `\%`). 
But this may be less word then encapsulate each comment in a rare used character,

Your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf[Script=Cyrillic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt[Script=Cyrillic]{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{CppCodeStyle}{
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
language={[ANSI]C++},
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
showstringspaces=false,
morekeywords={include, printf},
commentstyle={},
texcl=true,     %<---- added
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style={CppCodeStyle}]
/* Prints Hello World */
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
    printf ("Hello World!"); // This is an english commentary
    return 0; // А это русский комментарий
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]