# How to fix Xelatex warnings about undefined font shapes?

Tags: fonts, xetex, times

I need to fix this warnings with saving of Times New Roman and sizes of it.

Warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ftm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 49.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `PD1/ftm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `PD1/pdf/m/n' instead on input line 51.

LaTeX Font Info:   Try loading font information for PU+ftm on input line 51.
LaTeX Font Info:   No file PUftm.fd. on input line 51.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `PU/ftm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `PU/pdf/m/n' instead on input line 51.
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for T1+TimesNewRoman(1) 
                 on input line 54.
LaTeX Font Info: No file T1TimesNewRoman(1).fd. on input line 54.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/TimesNewRoman(1)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 54.
```

Test code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,russian,oneside,final]{extreport}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = TeX, Mapping = tex-text}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands = true]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontrm{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}

\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfontrm{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{Arial}
\newfontfamily\englishfonttt{Courier New}

\usepackage{mathtext}

\usepackage{extsizes}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}

\usepackage[final,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small\rmfamily\tt}

\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{C}{
   xleftmargin = 1.25cm,
   basicstyle  = \fontencoding{T1}\small\ttfamily,
   breaklines  = true,
   columns     = fullflexible
 }

 \begin{document}
   \section{Test section}
     \url{http://stackoverflow.com/}

     \begin{center}
       \begin{lstlisting}[style=C]
         #include <stdio.h>
         int main()
         {
             printf("Hello, World!");
             return 0;
         }
       \end{lstlisting}
     \end{center}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I’d also suggest removing `newtxmath`. Replace it with `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`.

Comment: @Davislor, test code in my question is a part of big latex project, where `newtxmath` fix a lot of warnings:
`LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/ftm/m/n' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/ftm/m/n' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/ftm/m/n' in size <29.86> not available
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/ftm/m/n' in size <14.93> not available
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/ftm/m/n' in size <29.86> not available
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/ftm/m/n' in size <14.93> not available
`

Comment: Adding the other commands I recommended should, if everything else is working, remove those warnings.

Comment: You’re including a lot of of different font commands that conflict with each other. I’m guessing that you copied these from different documents. In particular, you copied some document that sets the math alphabets to some non-standard font family named `ftm` that you don’t have. This is breaking, so you’re working around it by loading a different font package over it. You should delete all the font commands you don’t actually need.

Comment: @Davislor, I remove using of `mathtext`, because it was really useless, and remove `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}` because it has no effect. Now I have only `Warning: Font shape `T1/TimesNewRoman(1)/m/n' undefined` due lstlisting style, where used `\small` size of font

Comment: @Armoken All the packages egreg mentioned are redundant if you’re loading `polyglossia`. They’re legacy 8-bit fonts, and `polyglossia` brings in Unicode. You end up setting the current font encoding to T1 when you’re using a Unicode font. Also redundant: `\setromanfont`.if you already have `\setmainfont`.

Comment: @Davislor, I did what you said, but the warning didn't disappear, but I remove `\fontencoding{T1}` from setting `basicstyle` of `lstlisting` and it disappeared. But now I have strange looking russian words, but as said in [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108692/listing-with-mixed-english-and-russian-symbols-in-comments) addition of `texcl = true` to lst style fix it.

Comment: Add `[Script=Cyrillic]` after the definitions of `\cyrillicfont`, `\cyrillicfontsf`, etc. Delete the lines defining `\romanfont` and `\cyrillicfontrm`; they’re synonymous with the main font in `polyglossia`. If you end up with Russian words that are intelligible, but look “strange” to you, that’s just what the font you selected looks like. You can pick another `\cyrillicfont`.

Comment: In general, it’s a bad idea to mix legacy 8-bit font encodings or packages and modern Unicode fonts in the same document. You can, but it’s complicated and normally unnecessary. If you’re setting your fonts with `polyglossia`, you don’t want to load any legacy font packages, too. If you’re loading Unicode, you don’t want to switch to any 8-bit encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Davislor and @egreg I fix my code. The correct version of code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,russian,oneside,final]{extreport}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = TeX, Mapping = tex-text}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands = true]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}

\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{Arial}
\newfontfamily\englishfonttt{Courier New}

\usepackage[final,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small\rmfamily\tt}

\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{C}{
   xleftmargin = 1.25cm,
   basicstyle  = \small\ttfamily,
   breaklines  = true,
   columns     = fullflexible,
   texcl       = true
}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}
  \en{\url{http://stackoverflow.com/}}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=C]
      #include <stdio.h>
      int main()
      {
        printf("Hello, World!");
        return 0;
      }
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation?