# Minted Error "Undefined control sequence. \PYG" with TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker, minted, pygments

I have a Windows 10 computer and try to use the `minted` package to insert vhdl code into my LaTeX file. I did install Python and Pygments and added Python/scripts to the path. I also change the command lines of TeXmaker with `-shell-escape`. When I try to run a little example like this :

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,            % Papierformat
    oneside,            % einseitiger Druck
    %twoside,           % zweiseitiger Druck
    12pt,               % Schriftgröße
    onecolumn,          % einspaltiger Text
    %twocolumn,         % zweispaltiger Text
    openright,          % Kapitel dürfen nur auf einer rechten Seite beginnen
    openany,            % Kapitel dürfen rechts oder links beginnen
    parskip=half,       % eine halbe Zeile Abstand zw. Absätzen
    headsepline,        % Kopfzeilenlinie
    footsepline,        % Fußzeilenlinie
    bibliography=totoc, % Bibliographie im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    %idxtotoc           % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    ]{scrbook}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted} {vhdl}
process
begin
  CLK <= '1'; wait for 10 NS;
  CLK <= '0'; wait for 10 NS;
end process;
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I get the error...

> ```
> Undefined control sequence. \PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
> {#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop } l.2 \PYG{k}{process}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message
> was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I'
> and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

Comment: Well this works for me. Which distribution do you run (MikTeX, Texlive)?

Comment: Works for me (TeX Live 2016, Pygments version 2.0.2).

Comment: MikTeX, and I have no clue what i did wrong...

Comment: Have you tried to update your distribution https://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex?

Comment: Thanks for this comment, but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I had a similar issue in Linux and removing `_minted*` directory solved the problem. Another option could be to include the `minted` package with the option `cache=false`. You can do this by using `\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}` instead of `\usepackage{minted}`.

Source: [Github issue](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/92)

Comment: And how do you add this option ?

Comment: @Marine1 As written inside the GitHub issue: Write `\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}` instead of `\usepackage{minted}`.