# Undefined Sequence in Texmaker when using minted and -shell-escape package

Tags: texmaker, minted, pygments

I had some issue when using the `minted` package on Texmaker I read on an answer on tex.stackexchange that it was maybe better to download TeXStudio but it wasn't.  I heard it was something about `-shell-escape` in `Option> Configure Texmaker> Latex` and `Option> Configure Texmaker> PdfLaTex` so I added them both and now I'm having Undefined Sequence errors.

Here are some screenshots :

- Undefined Sequence error

[image]

- `Option> Configure Texmaker` modifications

[image]

And here is a minimal code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{minted}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{SQL}
params = {
      'database': 'la base de donnee',
      'user': 'utilisateur',
      'password': 'mot de passe',
      'host': 'souvent c'est amazon AWS',
      'port': 'le bon port'
    }

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute("""--- requete SQL
        SELECT ...""")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Can you help me to cope this problem? I like Texmaker, how can I remove TeXStudio?

Comment: Please, add a minimal code showing the issue.

Comment: @egreg Okay, just done, but actually the issue is about configuration and Control sequences.

Comment: Confirm if its a Possible Duplicate of Minted Error [“Undefined control sequence. \PYG” with TEXMaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367332/15717)

Comment: the screen shots are not much help, especialy as that view does not show the error message, just a (poor) summary of it. please show the error message from the log file, in a code section as used for the tex code, so line breaks are preserved.