# \PYGdefault undefined error in TeXstudio - how to remove the __minted_* folder?

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, minted, pygments

I installed TeXstudio and texlive with
`sudo apt install texlive-full` afterwards I installed the pygments with `sudo apt-get install python-pygments` and I used the command `% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]` inside my tex document and I used the `\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}` as the first package. But I still get the error message `\PYGdefault undefined.`

I found on a StackExchange page the advice, that there is a folder called `_minted_test`
that should be removed. But where can I find this folder?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373256

Comment: Try `\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}`.

Comment: I did this too. Sorry I forget to mention it.

Comment: There should be a folder in the same path as the tex file.

Comment: I do not have this folder. I always get the error message although it seems that the pdf-output is correctly genereated.

Comment: you say it is_minted_test via one link I read via that reference as  _minted-reference in the code so the advice was kill anything that's under _minted*