# Minted Errors on Linux (strange symbols, undefined control sequence)

Tags: minted

When using minted on Linux, I get the following error:

```
./out/master.out.pyg:2: Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG 
                   {#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.2 ... \PYG{n+nn}{numpy} \PYG{k}{as} \PYG{n+nn}{np}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

PDF output is also messed up:

[image: sadge]

I tried looking at this [question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367332/minted-error-undefined-control-sequence-pyg-with-texmaker), and after following the instructions to use `cache=false`, I still have the same error - the symbols are out of place and syntax highlighting doesn't work. This was not a problem on WSL on my current and previous computers, but once I switched to Linux, this appeared.

If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be very helpful. I would hate to have to go back to `lstlistings` package as it is a lot more of a hassle to work with.

Comment: Please post a complete MWE and log file. Linux problems often stem from outdated package versions.

Comment: For the first part, will do. However, an outdated package version would not really make sense - I was using TeX Live 2019 on my old computer (or whichever version `sudo apt install texlive` got me) and previous WSL and `minted` worked just fine, whereas I installed TeX Live 2022 on this computer. Unless you mean other packages that may be tangentially related to Linux?

Comment: No, I just mean that `apt` will often install old `texlive` versions. Another possibility is installed packages being shadowed by older ones somewhere on your machine. The log file will tell us if that's the case.

Comment: I assume you already tried deleting the `_minted*` directory, as suggested in the answer to the linked question?

Comment: Yup, I did. I was creating a MWE but it seems like it works fine there, but it does not work with my preamble attached. My preamble did not change (from the time I was using WSL) though, so I am confused.

Comment: Then you haven't found an MWE yet. ;-) Try starting with the whole preamble and removing things piece by piece, deleting the `_minted*` file and compiling every time. (Alternatively you can start with an empty preamble and build it up.) That way you should find the relevant bits.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm doing right now. I think it might have something to do with the theme I set. Will update the results as I go depending on how annoying Neovim decides to be with yanking and pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After way too much fussing with the preamble, it turns out it wasn't an error with `minted` but rather as I had thought - perhaps something with the style. And indeed, a capitalization error in the Pygments style caused the problem.

I tested my preamble line by line and the strange symbols appeared whenever I set the style and promptly disappeared otherwise. Testing with `echo hello | pygmentize -P style=style` also made it clear that this was the problem.

In my case, I failed to name my Pygments style `"stylename" : "stylename::ClassNameStyle"`.

That being said, I believe `minted` should fall back to the regular style if there is a problem with the given style (e.g. not being found), which is a question for another day.