# why tcolorbox example on pp. 345 doesn't work

Tags: tabularx, tcolorbox

I wish to improve my (very basic) knowledge about `tcolorbox` .. so I try to compile example in pp. 345 (chapter 18: Library "hooks"). Compiling it I receive 
warning:

```
\RequiredPackage{minted}{2011/09/17]
```

which I have installed by MikTeX package manager, then after forcing compilation
ask for

```
\minted@appathifexist=
```

etc

I use recent 64-bit  MikTeX with administrative privilege and WinEdt as editor. The example code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{array,tabularx}%,longtable,tabu

    \begin{document}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}% see tabularx
\tcbset{enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
        fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,
        colbacktitle=orange!30!white,%=Salmon!30!white
        coltitle=black,center title,
    tabularx={X||Y|Y|Y|Y||Y},% this sets ’before upper’ and ’after upper’
        before upper app={Group & One & Two & Three & Four & Sum\\
                          \hline\hline} }
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My table]
Red & 1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 10000.00\\\hline
Green & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 & 14000.00\\\hline
Blue & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 & 6000.00 & 18000.00\\\hline\hline
Sum & 6000.00 & 9000.00 & 12000.00 & 15000.00 & 42000.00
\end{tcolorbox}
    \end{document}
```

On the end I above code generate the following picture:

[image]

I expect that this would work "out of box" similarly as some other examples from manual, so do not know what I'm doing wrong or what I miss.

Comment: If I load also `colortbl` (for `\arrayrulecolor`) and run `pdflatex -shell-escape test`, I get the expected result. See [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aRwSl.png)

Comment: @egreg since tcolorbox internally loads `xcolor`, this `\documentclass[table]{article}` is alos enough. You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: You may want to see this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108661/11232

Comment: @HarishKumar, thank you for link. It is very usable.

Comment: @HarishKumar, I manage this. Now I need only to install Python (if I understand correctly). On https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ iI discover, that exist two versions: 2.7.10 and 3.4.3. What is difference between them and which one you suggest to install?

Comment: @Zarko: you can install any. 3.4.3 has more features. But for this job, even 2.7.10 is enough.

Comment: @HarishKumar, instaling Pythen was very challenge task. At this work your comments was of big help and very valuable. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the same output as you if I don't load `colortbl`: the error is!

```
Undefined control sequence.
\tcb@after@box ->\endtabularx \arrayrulecolor 
                                              {black}
l.20 \end{tcolorbox}
```

and `\arrayrulecolor` is a command of `colortbl`.

If I add `colortbl` to the list of packages (or, as Gonzalo Medina suggests, add `table` to the options for `\documentclass`), the output is

[image]

without any error.

Comment: at me this doesn't help. I still receive error: `You must invoke LaTex with the -shell-escape flag` and open file `tcbminted.code.tex` probably as source of error, but this time on the end I receive correct picture. And `TeXAuX` directory, where should be `log` file, is empty. Now I'm completely confused.

Comment: @Zarko Of course you have to add the `-shell-escape` option as I said in my comment: this is always needed for `minted`.

Comment: where? do I need to compile from DOS window? I try this, but receive error: you must have `pygmentize` instaled to use this package. Do I re-install tcolorbox?

Comment: @Zarko That depends on the front-end you're using. Pygmentize should of course be available on your machine: it's a Python library.

Comment: as far as know, I haven't installed python nor python library, except if this is automatically installed with some program.

Comment: @Zarko Well, if you don't have Python you can't have Pygmentize and can't use `minted`.

Comment: that one need to have python for use of hang library, is nowhere mentioned in the manual.  I'm now little disappointed. Anyway, I need to wait to my system administrator to help me fix this problem ( I haven't this privilege). Hopefully he will return from vacation in Monday :-(

Comment: @Zarko That's required for `minted`; `tcolorbox` just adds an interface to it. By itself, `tcolorbox` needs nothing else than a TeX distribution.

Comment: @eqreg, SE now complain that this become discussion ... can we move to chat?

Comment: @Zarko: Go to `Options` → `Execution Modes` and the in the window that opens, choose `pdflatex` (or any engine that you use). Add `--shell-escape` in `Switches`. See this picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bY3rH.png

Comment: @egreg, I like to test an answer before accept it. Due to issues with Python, I was not able to do this till to now. Installing of Python was challenging task ... with help of my (our) system administrator, I manage this today! Thank you for your help and patience.