# LaTex minted not working with MikTex, TexMaker under Windows 10

Tags: pdftex, highlighting, minted, syntax-highlighting

I used the minted library like defined  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108661/how-to-use-minted-under-miktex-and-windows-7).
I've installed Python under C:\Program Files (x86)\Python, added **C:\Program Files (x86)\Python** and **C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Scripts** to the PATH variable under Windows.

Python-Pip doesn't need to be insatalled anymore as provided with the installer from Python. I installed pygments with **pip install pygments** and configured TexMaker with the following: **pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex** in the pdfLateX section.

Deleting the _minted-*-Folder and recompiling the file also didn't work. The pygmentize.exe is located under the folder **C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Scripts** and seems to work properly :(

When compiling the example file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[mathescape,
                   linenos,
                   numbersep=5pt,
                   gobble=2,
                   frame=lines,
                   framesep=2mm]{csharp}
      string title = "This is a Unicode π in the sky"
      /*
      Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
      of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
      circle of diameter $d$.
      */
      const double pi = 3.1415926535
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

from the link I get the following error(s). Somehow I get a lot of undefined sequences???:

[image: Fail in minted package]

LOG FILE :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.9.3) 14 NOV 2016 20:41
entering extended mode
**./Test.tex
(Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\minted\minted.sty"
Package: minted 2016/10/31 v2.4.1 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds) That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds) that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds) In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\fvextra\fvextra.sty"
Package: fvextra 2016/09/02 v1.2.1 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvr
b
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count87
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty"
Package: fancyvrb 2008/02/07
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix
<2008/02/07> (tvz)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count88
\FV@InFile=\read1
\FV@TabBox=\box26
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count89
\FV@StepNumber=\count90
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty"
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\lineno\lineno.sty"
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count91
\output=\toks15
\linenoprevgraf=\count92
\linenumbersep=\dimen103
\linenumberwidth=\dimen104
\c@linenumber=\count93
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count94
\c@LN@truepage=\count95
\c@internallinenumber=\count96
\c@internallinenumbers=\count97
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen105
\bframerule=\dimen106
\bframesep=\dimen107
\bframebox=\box27
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
\c@FV@TrueTabGroupLevel=\count98
\c@FV@TrueTabCounter=\count99
\FV@TabBox@Group=\box28
\FV@TmpLength=\skip43
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStart=\count100
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStop=\count101
\FV@BreakIndent=\dimen108
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeft=\dimen109
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRight=\dimen110
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft=\dimen111
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRight=\dimen112
\c@FancyVerbLineBreakLast=\count102
\FV@LineBox=\box29
\FV@LineIndentBox=\box30
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\float\float.sty"
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count103
\float@exts=\toks16
\float@box=\box31
\@float@everytoks=\toks17
\@floatcapt=\box32
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty"
Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count104
\calc@Bcount=\count105
\calc@Adimen=\dimen113
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen114
\calc@Askip=\skip44
\calc@Bskip=\skip45
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count106
\calc@Cskip=\skip46
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\tools\shellesc.sty"
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 67.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\ifplatform\ifplatform.sty"
Package: ifplatform 2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\catchfile.sty"
Package: catchfile 2016/05/16 v1.7 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex"
\@xs@message=\write4
\integerpart=\count107
\decimalpart=\count108
)
Package: xstring 2013/10/13 v1.7c String manipulations (C Tellechea)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\framed\framed.sty"
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip47
\fb@frw=\dimen115
\fb@frh=\dimen116
\FrameRule=\dimen117
\FrameSep=\dimen118
)
\minted@appexistsfile=\read2
\minted@bgbox=\box33
\minted@code=\write5
\c@minted@FancyVerbLineTemp=\count109
\c@minted@pygmentizecounter=\count110
\@float@every@listing=\toks18
\c@listing=\count111
)
runsystem(if not exist _minted-Test mkdir _minted-Test)...executed.
(C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
\Gread@gobject=\count112
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
runsystem(for ^%i in (pygmentize.exe pygmentize.bat pygmentize.cmd) do set > Te
st.aex <nul: /p x=^%~$PATH:i>> Test.aex)...executed.
runsystem(del Test.aex)...executed.
(Test.aux)
\openout1 = `Test.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
(C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count113
\scratchdimen=\dimen119
\scratchbox=\box34
\nofMPsegments=\count114
\nofMParguments=\count115
\everyMPshowfont=\toks19
\MPscratchCnt=\count116
\MPscratchDim=\dimen120
\MPnumerator=\count117
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count118
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks20
)
\openout3 = `Test.pyg'.
(_minted-Test/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle) (_minted-Test/default.pygstyle)
(_minted-Test/5269120949F6EA64642025CBA828EB607A35B28C8CCC191544B1FB4F981E12EC.
pygtex
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.2 ...{}This is a Unicode π in the sky\PYGZdq{}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.2 ...{}This is a Unicode π in the sky\PYGZdq{}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.2 ...{}This is a Unicode π in the sky\PYGZdq{}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.2 ...{}This is a Unicode π in the sky\PYGZdq{}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \PYGZdq
{}This is a Unicode π in the sky\PYGZdq {}
l.2 ...{}This is a Unicode π in the sky\PYGZdq{}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
Missing character: There is no � in font cmtt10!
Missing character: There is no � in font cmtt10!
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...s is a Unicode π in the sky\PYGZdq
{}
l.2 ...{}This is a Unicode π in the sky\PYGZdq{}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.3 \PYG{c+cm}{/*}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.4 ...}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <7> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <5> on input line 4.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.5 ...hy{}sided regular polygon circumscribing a}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> of an $n$\PYGZhy
{}sided regular polygon circumscribing a
l.5 ...hy{}sided regular polygon circumscribing a}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.6 \PYG{c+cm}{ circle of diameter $d$.}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.7 \PYG{c+cm}{ */}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.8 ...G{n}{pi} \PYG{p}{=} \PYG{l+m}{3.1415926535}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.8 ...G{n}{pi} \PYG{p}{=} \PYG{l+m}{3.1415926535}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.8 ...G{n}{pi} \PYG{p}{=} \PYG{l+m}{3.1415926535}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.8 ...G{n}{pi} \PYG{p}{=} \PYG{l+m}{3.1415926535}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG
{#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.8 ...G{n}{pi} \PYG{p}{=} \PYG{l+m}{3.1415926535}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
) [1
{C:/Users/tim/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (Test.aux)
runsystem(del Test.pyg)...executed.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
4363 strings out of 493334
76502 string characters out of 3138399
181926 words of memory out of 3000000
7859 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3808 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
37i,5n,35p,820b,317s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MikTex/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/
Program Files (x86)/MikTex/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi5.pfb><C:/Program
Files (x86)/MikTex/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><C:/Program Files
(x86)/MikTex/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/M
ikTex/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr5.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MikTex/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MikTex/fonts/typ
e1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on Test.pdf (1 page, 68335 bytes).
PDF statistics:
34 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Log file for the files:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  minted.sty    2016/10/31 v2.4.1 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fvextra.sty    2016/09/02 v1.2.1 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb

  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
 upquote.sty    2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verbat
im
  lineno.sty    2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
catchfile.sty    2016/05/16 v1.7 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
  framed.sty    2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
supp-pdf.mkii
_minted-Test/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle
_minted-Test/default.pygstyle
_minted-Test/5269120949F6EA64642025CBA828EB607A35B28C8CCC191544B1FB4F981E12EC.p
ygtex
 ***********
```

**_minted-* files:**
5269120949F6EA64642025CBA828EB607A35B28C8CCC191544B1FB4F981E12EC.pygtex:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`\$=3\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8}]
    \PYG{k+kt}{string} \PYG{n}{title} \PYG{p}{=} \PYG{l+s}{\PYGZdq{}This is a Unicode π in the sky\PYGZdq{}}
    \PYG{c+cm}{/*}
\PYG{c+cm}{    Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter}
\PYG{c+cm}{    of an $n$\PYGZhy{}sided regular polygon circumscribing a}
\PYG{c+cm}{    circle of diameter $d$.}
\PYG{c+cm}{    */}
    \PYG{k}{const} \PYG{k+kt}{double} \PYG{n}{pi} \PYG{p}{=} \PYG{l+m}{3.1415926535}
\end{Verbatim}
```

and default.pygstyle and default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle but they both are empty.

Comment: I just installed python and pygments and had no problems with your example. I doubt that it is some permission problem. Can you show the content of the files in the `_minted` folder?

Comment: Yes, I will update the question ;)

Comment: The empty `default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle` is the problem. What do you get as content for `testpyg.txt` if you run on a command line in some empty folder `pygmentize -S default -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG >testpyg.txt` ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The generated file is in the answer (otherwise the question would be too long).

Comment: This looks ok (it is not empty). So the question is why your document doesn't create such a file. Move your Test.tex to an empty folder and compile there on the command line with `pdflatex --shell-escape Test`. Does this still fails?

Comment: No, this compiles properly and the PDF looks good (like in the example)...

Comment: Huh? No it works with TexMaker, too... I don't really get this :/ **EDIT:** Ok... I'm simply to stupid :D I set the pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex like pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex --> So no -- but only 1 -. That caused the problem :( :D

Comment: When the `.pygstyle` files exists minted doesn't recreate it, so it is to be expected that it works in texmaker too after a  successfull compilation. The real test is: delete the `_minted`-folder and then try again with texmaker. Does it work?

Comment: Ok, you're right. It doesn't work after deleting the minted folder... Well if it doesn't work, I guess it's no problem if it works via console. I will use it with the console then... Seems to be some issue with Texmaker I guess.

Comment: Looks so. But I really can't see why an empty `.pygstyle` is created if you compile through texmaker. That's rather odd. But I can't test as I don't have texmaker, in winedt there is no problem.

Comment: Ok, mhm... I will do this via the command line (or a batch file then) Is more easy then searching for the error here ;) But thank you for your time and advice :)

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is a little old, but for me it helps, to delete all the `.pygstyles` files in the minted-documentname folder.