# Syntax highlighting in LaTex define custom command

Tags: pdftex, highlighting, syntax-highlighting

According to my prior question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339154/latex-minted-not-working-with-miktex-texmaker-under-windows-10) I'm trying to highlight code in LaTeX and the minted package is not working properly. Now I wanted to ask if there is a possibility to do something like the following:

```
\newCommand\CustomHighlight{asdf=blue, text=red, test=green}
```

then use it like this `\CustomHighlight{asdf text Test}` to get the following result:
[image]

The syntax highlighting shouldn't be case-sensitive.

Comment: I am not sure you can do that easily with minted as it uses external programs to parse the code, but with `listings` it is pretty easy by using the `keywords` parameter (or defining a new language)

Comment: I don't want to use minted as it doesn't work... :( Can I do syntax highlighting with listing? I thought it is only making letters bold... Actually I want to highlight PL/SQL language like Notepad++ does... [image](https://abload.de/img/notepadhighlightingfodmud8.png)

Comment: Mhm, you're right, it looks quite good with listings: [link](https://www.overleaf.com/7024155srvgxvwcrgny#/24090523/)

Comment: minted could not do your example but it _does_ have a lexer for SQL, so if your real example is a language known to pygmentize then minted is probably the system of choice.

Comment: As I already told, minted doesn't work...

Comment: And listings supports SQL as well. But not PL/SQL.

Comment: Well, if you read my question correctly: There is the issue regarding the minted package again: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339154/latex-minted-not-working-with-miktex-texmaker-under-windows-10)

Comment: In the prior question I was using the example file from the link provided. I wrote: **"When compiling the example file from the link I get the following error(s)."** But I can provide the file there, too. **EDIT: Is done.**

Comment: sorry it's hard to spot a single `here` link when scanning questions, missed that, I added a (non) answer. I'll delete a few of the comments above, save the system getting cross with the length of the thread:-)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about this one. You're right with this, we don't want the system to crash :D